# What will be the difference between this two codes

Tags: c++

Why my second code is not giving expected result. I know using parenthesis it will work fine but why it is not giving correct answer without parenthesis. Can anyone please explain the logic behind this?

Here I used parenthesis and it gives correct answer, 4.

```cpp
// returns 4
int bitDiff () {
    int a=10, b=20;
    int count=0;
    while(a || b) {
        if ((a&1) != (b&1))
            count++;
        a=a>>1;
        b=b>>1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here I have not used parenthesis, so it is giving me wrong ans, 2.

```cpp
// returns 2
int bitDiff () {
    int a=10, b=20;
    int count=0;
    while(a || b) {
        if (a&1 != b&1)
            count++;
        a=a>>1;
        b=b>>1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `a&1 != b&1` is the same as `a&(1 != b)&1`

Comment: Operator precedence determines the grouping of terms in an expression and decides how an expression is evaluated. Certain operators have higher precedence than others; for example, the multiplication operator has a higher precedence than the addition operator. Take a look to the this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) for more information

Answer (score 0):

refer to [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) , as it states that :

> **10:**   ==  and !=  For equality operators = and ≠ respectively
>
> **11:**   a&b Bitwise AND

where **10** represents a higher Precedence over the **11**

so in the second example : `!=` will be evaluated first from left right then the `&` will be evaluated next.

so in the second example, in the **first iteration** : `(a&1 != b&1)` is equivalent to

```
a&(1 != b)&1
10&(1 != 20)&1
10&1&1 = 0
```

while in the first example, in the **first iteration** : `((a&1) != (b&1))` is equivalent to

```
(a&1) != (b&1)
(10&1) != (20&1)
0 != 0   which is equivalent to 0
```

as the operator `()` has a higher precedence over `!=`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand why it is not working.